# How to parse a custom key/value pair string into a JSON object in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I needed to parse a string of properties to a JSON object. Here is the input format:

`"var1=[val1] & var2=[val2] & var3=[val3] & var4=[val4]"`

And the desired output:

```js
{
   "var1": "val1",
   "var2": "val2",
   "var3": "val3",
   "var4": "val4"
}
```

I have the answer, see below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative method would be using `extract_all()`, then 'converting' the array into a property bad using `pack()` and `make_bag()`:

```
print str = "var1=[val1] & var2=[val2] & var3=[val3] & var4=[val4]"
| project Properties = extract_all(@"(?P<key>\w+)?=\[(?P<value>.*?)\]", dynamic(["key","value"]), str)
| mv-apply Properties on (
    summarize make_bag(pack(tostring(Properties[0]), Properties[1]))
)
```

Comment: that's usually better tested on a real and meaningful data set - you can run both N times against the same data set, then look at resource utilization (CPU, memory) and total duration using `.show queries`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ziad Hammoud for providing this cool workaround!

```
print str = "var1=[val1] & var2=[val2] & var3=[val3] & var4=[val4]"
| extend str = replace("\\] & ", "&", replace("=\\[", "=", str))
| project Properties = parse_urlquery(str)['Query Parameters']
| where Properties.var2== "val2"
```